# How to return the objects from inside a json list?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a func that make a get http request and after it return the following:

```
return json.decode(response.body);
```

The problem is that the response is a list, like this:

```
[
   {"name":"le me","score":"5,400,000,000","rank":"1"},
   {"name":"Scuzzy","score":"5,400,000,000","rank":"2"}
]
```

But i cant return this list, i need to return a map, the objects inside this list `[]`.

```
const requestRank = "https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore/a=869/ranking.json?table=0&category=0&size=5";

Future<Map> _runeRequest() async {
    http.Response response= await http.get(requestRank);
   print((response.body));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }


Widget buildRankTable() {
    return FutureBuilder<Map>(
      future: _runeRequest(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return _buildRank("1", "1", "1", "1", false);
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print(snapshot.error.toString());
              return _buildRank("2", "2", "2", "2", false);
            } else {
              String rank, player, xp;
                for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
                rank = snapshot.data["rank"];
                player = snapshot.data["name"];
                xp = snapshot.data["score"];
                print("º Rank=> " + rank);
                print("º player=> " + player);
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                  return _buildRank(rank, player, "2736", xp, false);
                else
                  return _buildRank(rank, player, "2736", xp, false);
              }
              return _buildRank(rank, player, "2736", xp, false);
            }
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I'm getting this error:

> type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr>'

I think the problem is that i'm returning a list to my `FutureBuilder` in my func `buildRankTable`. So i need to enter return a map, and dont a list in my response on func `_runeRequest`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the json into map with the code like below :
Map student = jsonDecode(jsonString);

More details are [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json).

Ideally, you'll have to create a class for the individual array and define a .fromJson method. This will give a better error handling and separate out the data and UI part.

Example below :

```
class Student {
final string name ;
.....

Student({
@required this.name,
// ... 

Student.fromJson(Map json)
  : this.name = json["name"],
    this.score = json["score"],
    this.rank = json["rank"]
}
```

Then you'll have to pass the JSON you receive from the server to this class in order to instantiate. You can make the list at the same time. Example below :

```
Future<List>Students getStudentList() {

   // ... API Call

    return (decodedBody["StudentList"] as List)
            .map((element) => Student.fromJson(element))
            .toList();
}
```

Comment: Now i'm getting this error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Answer (score 0):

**Create a model**

```
class LeaderboardModel{
    String name;
    String score;
    String rank;
    LeaderboardModel({this.name,this.score,this.rank});
    factory LeaderboardModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    return LeaderboardModel(
      name : json["name"],
      score : json["score"],
      rank : json["rank"],
    );
  }
}
```

**Create a function**

```
Future<List<LeaderboardModel>> readLeaderboard() async{
    final response = await http.get("https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore/a=869/ranking.json?table=0&category=0&size=5");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return parseLeaderboard(response.body);
    } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
}

List<LeaderboardModel> parseLeaderboard(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<LeaderboardModel>((json) => LeaderboardModel.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It give's me the following error:
type 'CastList<dynamic, Map<String, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'